# How to install Drools 6.5 in ServiceMix

Tags: bundle, drools, apache-servicemix

Is there a way for configure the latest version of Drools (6.5) in ServiceMix ? 
At the moment, the last complete supported  version is the 5.6.0 FINAL.

We have a version of our software that correctly runs on ServiceMix as bundle, but it's based on Drools 5.6 that has a preconfigured bundle in ServiceMix.
Now we want try to upgrade this bundle on 6.5 but seems that there isn't a way to do this.

Can someone help us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install using the drools-karaf-features:

This command makes the Drools 6.5.0.Final features to be available to ServiceMix:

```
karaf> features:addurl mvn:org.drools/drools-karaf-features/6.5.0.Final/xml/features
```

Then install the best feature for your application.

ref: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-karaf-features/6.5.0.Final